# substitution variable $BRANCH_NAME gives nothing while building

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm building docker images using cloud builder trigger, previously $BRNACH_NAME was working but now its giving null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the triggers that you have on cloud Build, as well as the Build details or build logs of that failed build? we may need more context to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my comment as an answer as it is too long for comment section.

According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_default_substitutions), you should have the possibility to use ***$BRANCH_NAME*** default substitution for builds invoked by triggers.

In the same documentation it is stated that:

> If a default substitution is not available (such as with sourceless
> builds, or with builds that use storage source), then occurrences of
> the missing variable are replaced with an empty string.

I assume this might be the reason you are receiving ***NULL***.

Have you performed any changes? Could you please provide some further information, such as your .yaml/.json file, your trigger configuration and the error you are receiving?

Comment: previously all substitution variable working properly, no changes made to it, but now all return null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in $BRANCH_NAME, I was using the resulted JSON  to fetch the branch name.

like,

```
"source": {
    "repoSource": {
      "projectId": "project_id",
      "repoName": "bitbucket_repo_name",
      "branchName": "integration"
    }
  }
```

and
I was using `build_details['source']['repoSource']['branchName']`

but now it's giving like

```
"source": {
    "repoSource": {
      "projectId": "project_id",
      "repoName": "bitbucket_repo_name",
      "commitSha": "ght8939jj5jd9jfjfjigk0949jh8wh4w"
    }
  },
```

so, now I'm using build_details['substitutions']['BRANCH_NAME'] and its working fine.